# How to add rdfs:label to OWLIndividual via OWLAPI?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, owl-api

I would like to add an `rdfs:label` to an `OWLIndividual`, I have the following:

```java
OWLIndividual newIndividual = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(name));
OWLLiteral lbl = factory.getOWLLiteral(name);
OWLAnnotation label =
  factory.getOWLAnnotation( 
    factory.getOWLAnnotationProperty(OWLRDFVocabulary.RDFS_LABEL.getIRI()), lbl);
```

Now, how can I associate the label to the individual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can associate the label the following way:

```java
OWLAxiom axiom = factory.getOWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom(newIndividual.asOWLNamedIndividual().getIRI(), label);
manager.applyChange(new AddAxiom(ontology, axiom));
```

In this case you need to work with a `NamedIndividual` in order to retrieve the IRI to assert the annotation.

Comment: In this case I'm using a literal as label. What should I write if I don't want specify any datatype (like in protege)? Many thanks.